# How to check if some variable is present in twig template in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

IN the every template i need to use this ststement

```
{{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
{{ form_javascript(form) }}
```

The the template gives error if the page is not haviing any form variable i.e its normal page.

Is there any way that i can check if `form` is present then load those otherwise not

```
if (form.present) then
{{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
    {{ form_javascript(form) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if form is defined  %}
    {{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
    {{ form_javascript(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html